# This row does not contain values for that table

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, drift, moor

I'm using Drift(moor).
When trying to get a sample of data using leftOuterJoin, the following situation happens:
The table that I join via leftOuterJoin returns null as a value.
I.e. leftOuterJoin itself works correctly but values from joined table are not read and return null.
As a result, I get a row where 1 or 2 columns have null values (depending on what table I join)
No one with such a situation is not faced?

```
final rows = await (select(favoritePlaces).join(
      [
        leftOuterJoin(
            cachedPlaces, cachedPlaces.id.equalsExp(favoritePlaces.placeId)),
      ],
    )).get();
```

[parsedExpressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Khu.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove ".get()" from the last line.
2. Add below lines after your code:

   final result = await rows.get();

   return result.map((resultRow) {
   return FavoritePlacesWithcachedPlaces(
   resultRow.readTable(favoritePlaces),
   resultRow.readTableOrNull(cachedPlaces),
   );
   }).toList();

where FavoritePlacesWithcachedPlaces object is something like:

```
class FavoritePlacesWithcachedPlaces {

final FavoritePlaces favoritePlaces;
final CachedPlaces? cachedPlaces;

FavoritePlacesWithcachedPlaces (this.favoritePlaces, 
this.cachedPlaces);}
```

The key point is using "readTableOrNull".